# Threejs basic rendering issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a basic configuration to render a geometry but I noticed that is rendered only if I put into the code this line about control:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.addEventListener('change', render );
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

if I try to delete this line the geometry is not visible. Below the entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MVC - example</title>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/BufferAttribute.js"></script>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/BufferGeometry.js"></script>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/EdgesHelper.js"></script>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="stats"></p>

<div id='maincanvas' style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height:  500px"></div>
<input type="button" onClick="test()" value="test"/>
<input type="button" onClick="render()" value="render"/>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var container, testbox, scene, camera, renderer, controls, scene_text, raycaster, projector, mouse2D;

    function init()
    {
        // SCENE
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // CAMERA
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth - 5, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 5;

        var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        var r = 4, phi = Math.PI / 4, theta = Math.PI / 4;
        camera.position.set(r * Math.cos(phi) * Math.sin(theta), r * Math.sin(phi), r * Math.cos(phi) * Math.cos(theta));

        // RENDERER
        if (Detector.webgl) {
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        }
        else {
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        }
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        renderer.autoClear = false;

        // CONTAINER
        container = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);*** if remove controls geometry is not visible
        // controls.addEventListener('change', render );
        // controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        // LIGHTS
        var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        light1.position.set(0, 1000, 1000);
        scene.add(light1);
        var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        light2.position.set(0, -1000, -1000);
        scene.add(light2);

        /////////////
        // OBJECTS //
        /////////////

        geometry0 = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry0.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
                              new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, -0.5)];
        geometry0.faces =
        [new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0), new THREE.Face3(4, 5, 6), new THREE.Face3(4, 6, 7), new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 5), new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4),
         new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 6), new THREE.Face3(1, 6, 5), new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 7), new THREE.Face3(2, 7, 6), new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 4), new THREE.Face3(3, 4, 7)];
        geometry0.computeFaceNormals();
        geometry0.computeVertexNormals();
        var material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xD1740A, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 });
        mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry0, material0);
        scene.add(mesh0);
        egh0 = new THREE.EdgesHelper(mesh0, 0x000);
        egh0.material.linewidth = 2;
        scene.add(egh0);

    }

    function render()
    {
        renderer.clear();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    function test()
    {
        init();
        render();
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, your camera's position didn't set properly so it looks at somewhere else. Currently your object's position is at (0,0,0), so you should look at the right direction and you will see your object.

You need to look at somewhere like:

```
camera.position.set(0,0,10);
```

Beside that, for animation purposes you need to add following code at the end of render function. But if you don't have any animation its okay to ignore it:

```
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: How can I check what is my object's position?

Comment: @GiuseppeMatrizzi by default its (0,0,0) ... you can set it using: mesh0.position.set(x,y,z)